# How to reproject aqua modis images / ocean color?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am working with aqua modis, ocean color, L2 - SST image but in order to do I must reproject it. I use the gdal_translate to convert the format of the image but reprojection is becoming very difficult...

When I download it, it has a north down projection. This image has 5 bands and the two first bands are the lat lon in decimal degrees.

Do you know how can I reproject them by using the band 1 and band 2 as coordinates?

Comment: I finally found the solution which was a bit different than the one I had in my mind. I read the ocean_color forum and they proposed to use the beam-visat software (made by ESA) to reproject and process the raster data. The result was correct